# Почему нельзя отвечать?

Tags: discussion

Уважаемые !
На форуме я недавно. Порой читаю вопросы и мне есть что сказать по существу, но форум не дает мне отвечать, говорит, что требуется не менее 50 баллов.
Кто знает почему это так и как бы набрать 50 баллов, чтобы все-таки можно было общаться ?
Например я точно знаю из старых книг и народных преданий, что значит "Первый блин комом".
Ни комки ни медведи здесь ни при чем. Происходит от древних обрядов с жертвоприношениями. Комы - потом транформировалось в Кумы и с христианством приобрело другой смысл. Комы это души жертв. И им так же как на поминках предлагают первый блин , чтобы задобрить. Это вкратце. Но ответить человеку не могу из-за баллов.
ЗЫ. Если накидаете баллов -большое спасибо.

Comment: Есои правила не изменились, вы можете отвечать. Не можете давать комментарии, это да. Но должен вам сказать, что ответы здесь ценятся аргументированные, а не "я точно знаю". И, кстати,  этот вопрос надо было задать на мете. Надеюсь, его туда и перенесут.

Comment: *Если накидаете баллов -большое спасибо.* - иногда я это делаю, но вам-то за что?  -(+) Вы можете  отвечать. https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges Попробуйте ответить - и если ваш ответ понравится, баллов вам накидают.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получить баллы, задавайте вопросы и давайте ответы на уже существующие. Иных способов обойти ограничения, установленные системой, нет.

Comment: В том и проблема, что давать ответы на существующие вопросы нельзя.При попытке отправить ответ возникает подсказка о необходимости 50 баллов. Приходим к некоторому противоречию - комментарий не оставить, т к нет баллов,а баллы не набрать, т к невозможно оставлять комментарии.

Comment: @АлексейОсипов попробуйте отвечать не на защищенные вопросы. https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user Никаких санкций к вашей учетной записи не применялось.